# how to print the result from pack function?

Tags: perl

I like to verify what pack does. I have the following code to give it a try.

```
$bits = pack 'N','134744072';
```

how to print bits ?

I did the following:

```
printf ("bits = %032b \n", $bits);
```

but it does not work.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the binary representation of a number, use

```
my $num = 134744072;
printf("bits = %032b\n", $num);
```

If you want the binary representation of a string of bytes, use

```
my $bytes = pack('N', 134744072);
printf("bits = %s\n", unpack('B*', $bytes));
```

Comment: anyway to check what is in $bytes before it is unpacked ?

Comment: What do you want to check? If you want to check that it contains (something that could be) a string of bytes, you can use `$bytes =~ /^[\x00-\xFF]*\z/`

Comment: I like to print out the content in $bytes before it is unpack.  thanks so much !!

Comment: To print the bytes in `$bytes`, use `print $fh $bytes;`

Comment: I tried to understand what this statement "join '.', unpack 'C4', pack 'N', shift" does piece by piece.  thanks a lot for help !!

Comment: Given the number 0x12345678, returns the numbers 0x12, 0x34, 0x56 and 0x78. The decimal representation of those numbers are then joined by `.`. Specifically, you're probably getting the dotted representstion of an IPv4 address from its numerical form.

Answer (score 1):

The [Devel::Peek](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Peek) module (which comes with Perl) allows you to examine Perl's representation of the variable.  This is probably more useful than just a raw `print` when you're dealing with binary data rather than printable character strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Peek qw(Dump);

my $bits = pack 'N','134744072';

Dump($bits);
```

Which produces output like this:

```
SV = PV(0xaedb20) at 0xb15650
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0xb06630 "\10\10\10\10"\0
  CUR = 4
  LEN = 10
```

The 'SV' at the beginning indicates that this is a dump of a 'scalar value' (as opposed to say an array or a hash value).

The 'SV = PV' indicates that this scalar contains a string of bytes (as opposed to say an integer or floating point value).

The 'PV = 0xb06630' is the pointer to where those bytes are located.

The "\10\10\10\10"\0 is probably the bit you're interested in.  The double quoted string represents the bytes making up the contents of this string.
Inside the string, you would typically see the bytes interpreted as if they were ASCII, so the byte 65 decimal would appear as 'A'. All non-printable characters are displayed in octal with a preceding `\`.

So your `$bits` variable contains 4 bytes, each octal '10' which is hex 0x08.

The LEN and CUR are telling you that Perl allocated 10 bytes of storage and is currently using 4 of them (so `length($bits)` would return 4).

Comment: Wow, what an awful way of doing `printf '%vX', $bits;`. `Dump` is to look at internals, which the OP has no interest in.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, one of the Perl mottos is "There's more than one way to do it". I demonstrated exactly that - one way to do it. Examining alternative approaches and assessing their relative merits is instructional. Also, how do you know the OP (or indeed anyone else reading the question) has no interest in Perl's internals?

Comment: That doesn't mean all ways are equal. You picked one that's very confusing, and overloads the reader with unnecessary information, and doesn't always provide the correct results (e.g. for magical vars). You didn't even mention which string to look at when there's more than one printed (e.g. for vars with UTF8=1).

Comment: You seem determined to pick a fight. I never claimed that all ways are equal. I did specifically mention which string to look at in the example which was exactly what the OP would have seen. The example did not involve a string of code points, so no I did not mention the UTF8 version which was not in the example.

Comment: Re "*You seem determined to pick a fight*", I don't see how there's any doubt that my comment attacked your answer. // Re "*I never claimed all ways are equal*", I'm confused. Are you saying you agree with my initial comment? It sure didn't sound like that.

Comment: Re "*The example did not involve a string of code points, so no I did not mention the UTF8 version which was not in the example.*", huh? The UTF8 flag has nothing to do with whether the string is a string of code points or not. It can be set for non-code points, and it can be set for code points.

Comment: Of course I agree that your comment attacked my answer - that much is obvious. I find it ironic that you admonish me for providing "unnecessary information" and then repeatedly drop in factoids about UTF8 which could hardly be less relevant.

Comment: I didn't "drop factoids"; I pointed out that your statement was nonsense. Would you rather I have said it was wrong without saying why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're hoping to achieve by this extended series of pointless replies. I assume you just want to have the last say. That's fine. Have the last say. I'm done.